# Cannot serialize abstract class com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a data which have an `String` property and a list with `X` model.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class TimeZoneModel(
    @Json(name = "countryName")
    val countryName: String,
    @Json(name = "timeZonesPerCountry")
    var timeZonesPerCountry: MutableList<FullTimeZone> = mutableListOf()
)
```

FullTimeZone class

```
data class FullTimeZone(@Json(name = "language") val timeZone: TimeZone, @Json(name = "gmtFormat") val gmtFormat: String)
```

But when i run the program it give an exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize abstract class com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone
    for class com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone timeZone
    for class class app.package.name.models.FTimeZone
    for java.util.List<class app.package.name.models.FTimeZone> timeZones
    for class app.package.name.models.TimeZoneCountry
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$LookupChain.exceptionWithLookupStack(Moshi.java:388)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:157)
        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:262)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:105)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:74)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:54)
        at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:38)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
        at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:262)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:145)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:105)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:79)
        at class app.package.name.utils.PreferenceDataStoreManager.<init>(PreferenceDataStoreManager.kt:24)
        at class app.package.name.ApplicationClass.onCreate(ApplicationClass.kt:14)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
            ...Your post appears to contain code that is not properly
```

**NOTE** TimeZone class is **icu4j_1.jar** lib from [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-67-1)

Comment: Don't try to serialize classes you don't control reflectively. Add an adapter for this class.

Answer (score 1):

Full Timezone class also need to annotated with
`@JsonClaaa(generateAdapter = true)`

Explanation:
Any class annotated with `@JsonClaaa(generateAdapter = true)` requires its properties to have a way to serialize.
In case of string, Moshi knows how to serialize it, but a custome class needs a way to be serialized and that's what you will do by annotating it by `@JsonClaaa(generateAdapter = true)`